# Index/match if greater than

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Hoping someone can help me with my trouble with an index/match formula.

Column B has a list of names, column C has the frequency of an action taken (sales made) whilst column D has the average sales value.

I've created in column G a track of the 6 highest sales which has worked great:

> =LARGE($D$8:$D$13, 2)

Then I've used column F to determine the name that matches each sales average:

> =INDEX($B$8:$B$13, MATCH(G4, $D$8:$D$13, 0))

So far so good! However, I'd like to only include the sales average if that individual has had more than 3 sales. IE; the value in column C is >3.

Can any one provide help or suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [an array formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/nth-largest-value-with-criteria):

```
=LARGE(IF(range=criteria,values),n)
```

so for your case:

```
=LARGE(IF($C$8:$C$13>3,$D$8:$D$13), 2)
```

press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a helper column to filter out the values you don't need before applying `=LARGE()` in the very beginning, like this:

```
=IF($C8>3, $D8, "")
```

Then do `=LARGE()` to this column instead:

```
=LARGE($X$8:$X$13, 2)
```

Comment: This worked as well, but the user below an array solution that keeps the page neater. For smaller projects though I will certainly use your solution. Thank you!