# Excel Match Index greater than zero dynamic range

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I currently use the following code to retrieve information from one worksheet to another:

```
=INDEX('Bravo'!$A:$AV,MATCH(1,Bravo!A:A=$D$4)*('Bravo'!C:C=$B7),0)MATCH($C7,'Bravo'!$1:$1,0))
```

Alpha Worksheet Display
[image]

1. ID
2. OP_ALPHA_WTR_TEMP:1-1(Identifies what stage water temp is at)
3. Strl Time(Start time)

The way it works is it takes three pieces of information from the "Alpha" Worksheet, cross-references it to the "Bravo" Spreadsheet and returns the value it finds in the information provided.

I need to do something similar with the Water_Temp section, which is also in the first screen shoot. This cross-reference would be done on another worksheet(Charlie). The only thing is that I'm trying to see if it can be done with only using the ID in the D4 cell of the Alpha worksheet.

If you take a look at the attached Charlie Worksheet, it will only have one result that is above zero for the whole row.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to match the ID from the Alpha worksheet to the Charlie worksheet and then return the value of that row that is above zero.

Charlie Worksheet Display
[image]

I need to be able to use dynamic look up since the list in column A of the Charlie worksheet will increase or decrease ID values depending on the length of the start time and end time look up.  There is always going to be 6 Columns for the Charlie worksheet.

There were a couple of answers in Stackoverflow that came close that I tried to piece together but I was unsuccessful in attaining what I was looking for.

[Match Link Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451683/excel-match-if-greater-than-zero)
[Match Link Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971452/index-match-if-greater-than)

Any information that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: After playing around with it for a couple of days I found a formula that worked:

=MAX(INDEX(('Charlie'!A4:A100=D4)*('Charlie'!B4:G100>0)*'Charlie'!B4:G100,))

This formula was placed on the "Alpha" "Water Temp" "D4" cell workbook. It referenced "Charlie" workbook Column A4 thru A:100,  matched the ID from D4 Alpha workbook and once it found it in the column it went through that whole row and brought back the first value it found that was greater than zero. 

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it for a couple of days I found a formula that worked: `=MAX(INDEX(('Charlie'!A4:A100=D4)*('Charlie'!B4:G100>0)*'Cha‌​rlie'!B4:G100,))` This formula was placed on the "Alpha" "Water Temp" "D4" cell workbook. It referenced "Charlie" workbook Column A4 thru A:100, matched the ID from D4 Alpha workbook and once it found it in the column it went through that whole row and brought back the first value it found that was greater than zero. Hope this helps someone in the future.